# How to make a program like game maker or scrolling game dev kit 2

Tags: c++, game-maker

Are there any tutorials on how to make a program like game maker? I know python and c++ but am willing to learn other languages if need be. I would also like the program to generate source code in a language designed for the program that can be edited by the user, so should I just use c++ to generate code and then later, when the user want to test their game, compile that code to run? Thank you in advanced. 
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to ask this question, I wonder if its a good idea for you to make your own IDE + Compiler + Programming language.

If you really want to - I'd use C++ for the compiler and Java for the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own game engine then the IDE.
It's not that easy.
I'd use SDL for the engine (C++) and Python(wxPython) IDE.